# toLabel working in developer console but not in apex

Tags: apex, soql, lightning-web-components

I am having an issue with translations for the product categories.

Example controller :

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<ProductCategory> getCategoriesTest(){
    return [SELECT toLabel(Name), ParentCategoryId From ProductCategory WHERE ParentCategoryId = 'xxx'];
}
```

This query works perfectly fine in the developer console and I get the Category Name in the proper language.

But when I call the controller from a lightning web component (I checked that the locale and language of the user were correct in the controller with UserInfo.getLocale() and UserInfo.getLanguage()), I always get the Category Name in english.

Am I doing something wrong or is this an issue with Salesforce ?

Thank you !
Julien

Comment: What is the API version of your class? Based on [this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197961/tolabel-in-auraenabled-apex-lightning-controller) this was an issue at one point and it may be resolved in a different API version.

Comment: The controller and the lwc calling it were both API version 50, I upgraded them to 52 but this does not solve the issue

Comment: `ProductCategory` seems like a unique object, it has its [own metadata type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_productcategorydatatranslation.htm) just for translating. It could be that this isn't supported in an AuraEnabled method (in which case, definitely raise a case with Salesforce). If it's not, you may be able to try SOSL or consider referencing the `ProductCategoryDataTranslation` metadata to get the translation you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for this @nbrown, I was able to get the translated labels from the `ProductCategoryDataTranslation`

Comment: @nbrown, can you post as an answer to the post so I can accept it as the answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would raise this issue to Salesforce to determine if it is a gap in the implementation of the toLabel function (it sounds like it may be).

If `toLabel` doesn't work in this situation, there is a workaround. ProductCategory metadata, since it's a part of the B2B expansion to Salesforce, operates a bit differently from other objects. Normally `toLabel()` would only work on picklist values in a SOQL query, but for ProductCategory there is a [separate set of metadata to enable translation (`ProductCategoryDataTranslation`)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_productcategorydatatranslation.htm) via Translation Workbench. You should be able to reference `ProductCategoryDataTranslation` metadata in Apex to get translated values directly as an alternative.